# Google Earth Engine and Sentinel 5p

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

I am working on a project to better understand possible applications of the Sentinel 5p dataset within GEE. If anyone has current or past projects that they are willing to share, please feel free to do so. This is out of pure curiosity and academic purposes.